# Prestashop - why button by default redirects to ../cart?

Tags: prestashop

I've created a form with a submit button, but it opens cart. It should call module front controller. 
How to fix it?

```
<form action="{$url}" method="post">
            First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Maybe that's the url you have in `{$url}`, when the form is submitted is redirected to that url.

Comment: @Rolige {$url} is equal to http://localhost/op/en/module/offers/handler where offers is module name and handler is controller name.

Answer (score 1):

OMG. I'm so stupid. I was using displayProductAdditionalInfo hook. And my form that I created was in another form which redirects to cart...

Answer (score 0):

Check your action value. html forms will redirect to action url.

Comment: action value is equal to localhost/op/en/module/offers/handler where offers is module name and handler is controller name.. When I create <button>Test</button> it also redirects me to cart.